# easy_install a list of packages from a txt file with Salt

Tags: saltstack

Salt already provides a pip state which can be used as:

```
pip.installed:
  - requirements: requirements.txt
```

I want to do the same with `easy_install` and with as minimal juggling as possible. I can understand that I can loop over a command output in Jinja but I'll only prefer that as a last resort.

Please provide some pointers on how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

Salt doesn't have an 'easy_install' execution module or state, but you could easily use cmd.run to execute your easy_install command.

Docs on cmd.run state are here: http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#module-salt.states.cmd

It would be something like this:

```
easy_install mypackage:
  cmd.run
```

Comment: also, it shouldn't be too hard to create an easy_install execution module and state, especially if they were based off the corresponding pip modules. But that's probably more work than you'd want to just solve this specific task .